# Kafka Streams Hopping Window

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible that a Hopping window advances just by time (without receiving a new event) so that automatically old events are removed if there is no update for that key?

Imagine the revenue of a product the last 14 days. But if the product gets not sold, the aggregated revenue should be 0 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since the hopping window is defined by two properties: the window’s size and its advance interval (aka “hop”) and also it is also a overlapping window, it is advised to use Tumpling windows in such scenarios. And as you know each windows are tracked by per key and a little bit of programming logic you can acheive this or KSQL helps here.